# SQL Create Table Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, create-table

I want a column in sql to be the sum of 2 columns in the same table.
For example:
columns : score, assists, rebound
While creating this table ı want score = assist + rebound value.

```
CREATE TABLE macDetay (
macID INT , oyuncuID INT , 
CONSTRAINT PKDETAY PRIMARY KEY (macID, oyuncuID),
CONSTRAINT FK1 FOREIGN KEY(macID) REFERENCES Mac(macID), 
CONSTRAINT FK2 FOREIGN KEY(oyuncuID) REFERENCES Oyuncu(oyuncuID),
macSkor INT, asistSayisi INT,reboundSayisi INT, 
CONSTRAINT skor CHECK (macSkor = asistSayisi+ReboundSayisi))
```

I'm forcing to enter the sum in my way but I want it to be automatic

Comment: You can use the computed column in a table as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add computed column in your statement. It's simple.
computedColumnName as (col1 + col2)

```
CREATE TABLE macDetay (
    macID INT
    ,oyuncuID INT
    ,CONSTRAINT PKDETAY PRIMARY KEY (
        macID
        ,oyuncuID
        )
    ,CONSTRAINT FK1 FOREIGN KEY (macID) REFERENCES Mac(macID)
    ,CONSTRAINT FK2 FOREIGN KEY (oyuncuID) REFERENCES Oyuncu(oyuncuID)
    ,macSkor AS (asistSayisi + ReboundSayisi)
    ,asistSayisi INT
    ,reboundSayisi INT
    )
```